# How to filter queryset with custom function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models and I am trying to apply some filtering.

Basically I have this player model that can have multiple Experiences, and I want to send on my query params `xp` that will receive a value in years, and my queryset should only retrieve the players with at least that amount of years of experience in total.

The `calc_player_experience` method reads throw the players experience and calculates de amount of experience the player has and returns `true` or `false` if it meets the `xp` received on the query params.

How do I apply a function to `model.filter()`? is that a thing?

```
models.py

class Player(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255, blank=True)

class Experience(BaseModel):
    player = models.ForeignKey(
        "players.Player", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    team = models.CharField(_("team"), max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField(_("start_date"), null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(_("end_date"), null=True, blank=True)
```

```
views.py

class PlayersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filters the players to retrieve only those not archived and approved"""
        queryset = Player.objects.filter(is_approved=True, is_active=True)
        return apply_filters(self, queryset)

def apply_filters(obj, queryset):
    """Apply filters to given queryset"""

    xp = dict(obj.request.GET).get("xp", [])
    if xp:
        queryset = queryset.filter(lambda player: obj.calc_player_experience(player,xp[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py you need to return the queryset from the apply_filters function. Make sure you have a queryset returned even if it is empty.

```
def apply_filters(obj, queryset):
    """Apply filters to given queryset"""

    xp = dict(obj.request.GET).get("xp", [])
    if xp:
        queryset = queryset.filter(lambda player: obj.calc_player_experience(player,xp[0])) 
    return queryset
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. The problem is I am not able to use the function on queryset.filter(<function>). How can I do that?

Comment: If the function returns a list of ids that you expected what you can do is use Items.objects.filter(id__in=function_that_returns_list_of_ids())